# How to update a char in a String?

Tags: string, rust

I'm trying to update a `char` in a `String`, but can't seem to be able to do that.

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = "poyo".to_string();
    // s[1] = 'i'; or s.get_mut(1) = 'i'; can't do either
    println!("{}", s); // expecting "piyo"
}
```

I know why this happens (`String` does not implement `IndexMut<usize>`), but I don't know how to resolve this...

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=188a5cb8ee442958bdca286b3a75a265&version=undefined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on the sort of `String` you are dealing with; if you are working with ASCII **only** (which means every character is one byte in size and you can just directly manipulate the underlying `Vec<u8>`), you could do the following:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = "poyo".to_string();
    let mut bytes = s.into_bytes();
    bytes[1] = 'i' as u8;

    unsafe { s = String::from_utf8_unchecked(bytes) }

    println!("{}", s);
}
```

or:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = "poyo".to_string();

    unsafe {
        let bytes = s.as_bytes_mut();
        bytes[1] = 'i' as u8;
    }

    println!("{}", s);
}
```

If, however, you are (potentially) working with multi-byte characters (which is the whole reason why `String` doesn't implement `IndexMut` or even `Index`), the safe way to do it would be to use the [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/str/struct.Chars.html) iterator, walk over it and create a new `String` based on its elements:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "poyo".to_string();
    let iter = s.chars();
    let mut new = String::new();

    for (i, mut c) in iter.enumerate() {
        if i == 1 { c = 'i'; }
        new.push(c);
    }

    println!("{}", new);
}
```