# Trying to make a word matrix creator, can't loop through the positions of the vector?

Tags: rust

I've been trying to build a program that effectively does something similar to this:

```
H, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, E, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, L, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, L, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, O
```

I'm attempting to replicate this using a user_word_length * user_word_length matrix, then changing the diagonal to be said word. But i've been having a lot of trouble figuring out Vectors and how to make them work for this project. I've just gotten into rust and after googling for about an hour now, I just can't seem to find the solution! :(

The current error i'm getting is "`the type 'str' cannot be indexed by 'usize' string indices are ranges of 'usize'`".

I've tried changing v[iter][iter] 'iter' with numbers, other variables, even tried changing the declaration of the function itself. I just can't seem to figure out what i'm missing here.

I've also tried making the vectors and the iter itself mutable, which also did not fix the problem.

Finally, I changed the create_matrix function syntax to use '&str' instead of 'String', and even that didn't seem to fix it.
Any ideas?

```rust
// Imported Crates
use std::io;

fn main() {
    // Beginning of Program
    println!("Welcome to the Word Matrix Creator!\n");
    let user_word = grab_word();
    let user_word_length: usize = user_word.chars().count();
    println!("The user word is {} and the amount of characters is {}", user_word, user_word_length);
}

fn grab_word() -> String {
    // Create user_word
    let mut user_word = String::new();
    
    // Ask user for word & assign to user_word
    println!("\nPlease input the word: ");
    io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut user_word)
            .expect("Attempt to read input was unsuccessful! ERROR: ");
    
    // Trim and capitalize the word. Remove Newline and Carriage Return
    user_word = user_word.trim().to_ascii_uppercase().replace('\n', "").replace('\r', "");

    // Call verify_word in grab_word
    if verify_word(&user_word) {
        // continue program
        println!("Operation Success!");
        return user_word;
    }

    else {
        println!("The word provided does not meet the requirements.\nTerminating Program\n");
// **********Figure out how to terminate program*************
        return "NULL".to_string();
    }
}

fn verify_word(user_word: &str) -> bool {
    // Check to make sure word is alphanumeric
    return user_word.chars().all(char::is_alphanumeric);

}

fn create_matrix(user_word: &str, user_word_length: usize) -> Vec<&str> {
    // Initialize vector!
    let mut v: Vec<&str> = vec!["0"; user_word_length * user_word_length];
    let mut iter: usize = 0;
    for x in user_word.chars() {
        v[iter][iter] = x;
    }
    
    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of Rust's guarantees about every `&str` and `char` being valid UTF-8, you are better off using a `Vec<char>` than a string, so that you can actually update it. Otherwise, your best bet would be to [create a new string as you iterate through the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132141/how-to-update-a-char-in-a-string). When you want that "string", you can collect the vector and print it out:

```rust
use std::io;
use std::process;

fn main() {
    // Beginning of Program
    println!("Welcome to the Word Matrix Creator!\n");
    let user_word = grab_word();
    let user_word_length: usize = user_word.chars().count();
    println!("The user word is {} and the amount of characters is {}", user_word, user_word_length);
    
    println!("The matrix is:");
    for s in create_matrix(&user_word, user_word_length) {
        println!("{}", s.iter().collect::<String>());
    }
}

fn grab_word() -> String {
    // Create user_word
    let mut user_word = String::new();
    
    // Ask user for word & assign to user_word
    println!("\nPlease input the word: ");
    io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut user_word)
            .expect("Attempt to read input was unsuccessful! ERROR: ");
    
    // Trim and capitalize the word. Remove Newline and Carriage Return
    user_word = user_word.trim().to_ascii_uppercase();

    // Call verify_word in grab_word
    if verify_word(&user_word) {
        // continue program
        println!("Operation Success!");
        return user_word;
    } else {
        println!("The word provided does not meet the requirements.\nTerminating Program\n");
        // terminate with `std::process::exit`
        process::exit(1);
    }
}

fn verify_word(user_word: &str) -> bool {
    // Check to make sure word is alphanumeric
    return user_word.chars().all(char::is_alphanumeric);
}

fn create_matrix(user_word: &str, user_word_length: usize) -> Vec<Vec<char>> {
    // Initialize vector!
    let mut v: Vec<Vec<char>> = vec![vec!['0'; user_word_length]; user_word_length];
    let mut iter: usize = 0;
    
    for x in user_word.chars() {
        v[iter][iter] = x;
        iter += 1;
    }
    
    return v;
}
```

Another couple of minor things I noticed:

- [`std::process::exit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html) terminates early from anywhere in the program
- it looks like you forgot to increment your index in the matrix loop
- [`trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) should remove `\n` and `\r` for you, since those are whitespace characters, so I don't think your replacements are doing anything.

Comment: Even better, `Vec<u8>` (unless you need Unicode, but in this case you're better staying with `String`). `Vec<char>` requires as four-fold space.